# Not able to turn on HealthKit capability

Tags: xcode, ios9, healthkit, watchos-2

I'm trying to experiment with HealthKit on both iOS 9 and WatchOs 2.0, but when I try to turn on HealthKit in the project's Capabilities page, I get the following error message:

> Link HealthKit.framework
>
> The framework 'HealthKit.framework' was not found in the SDK for this
>   target.

The same happens for both the iOS App and the WatchKit App Extension.

I tried to manually find the framework in **Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library**, but it's not there either.

I'm using XCode 7.0 Beta 4.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I excluded Xcode and re-downloaded it.
HealthKit was suddenly there again.

Go figures..